# Qt.labs.controls: TabButtons don't click

Tags: qt, qml

I use Qt 5.6 labs controls. I use TabBar and SwipeView. But TabButtons don't click. I want to paint background of the Item control and so I use Rectangle but the rectangle is fill all screen. My app and I want this: [IMAGE](http://s10.postimg.org/9aimg7ajt/tabbarandswipeview.png).
And my code is this:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import Qt.labs.controls 1.0

Rectangle {
  TabBar {
      id: tabbar
      width: parent.width
      currentIndex: view.currentIndex

      TabButton {
        text: qsTr("1")
      }

      TabButton {
        text: qsTr("2")
      }

      TabButton {
        text: qsTr("3")
      }
    }

    SwipeView {
      id: view
      anchors.fill: parent
      currentIndex: tabbar.currentIndex

      Item {
        id: tab0
        Rectangle {
          color: "red"
        }
      }


      Item {
        id: tab1
        Rectangle {
          anchors.fill: parent // -> This command is fill all screen so I don't click TabButtons.
          color: "blue"
        }
      }


      Item {
        id: tab2
        Rectangle {
          anchors.fill: parent
          color: "lightblue"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made the `SwipeView` fill its parent, but the `TabBar` has the same parent and occupies some of the same space. `SwipeView` is an interactive control, so it accepts mouse events. The `SwipeView` is also declared after the `TabBar`, which means it has a higher stacking/Z order. These two things combined mean that `TabBar` is never going to get mouse events.

You can ensure that both have enough space by using [`ColumnLayout`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-columnlayout.html), for example:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import Qt.labs.controls 1.0

Window {
    visible: true

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent

        ColumnLayout {
            anchors.fill: parent
            spacing: 0

            TabBar {
                id: tabbar
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                currentIndex: view.currentIndex

                TabButton {
                    text: qsTr("1")
                }

                TabButton {
                    text: qsTr("2")
                }

                TabButton {
                    text: qsTr("3")
                }
            }

            SwipeView {
                id: view
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                currentIndex: tabbar.currentIndex

                Item {
                    id: tab0
                    Rectangle {
                        color: "red"
                    }
                }


                Item {
                    id: tab1
                    Rectangle {
                        anchors.fill: parent // -> This command is fill all screen so I don't click TabButtons.
                        color: "blue"
                    }
                }


                Item {
                    id: tab2
                    Rectangle {
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        color: "lightblue"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is true answer.